# Value Type from Arbitrary Iterator in Template Function

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl, iterator

I am trying to retrieve value type from iterator parameter. How could I do that? I googled it and see some iterator_trait features, but couldn't figure out how to implement it on my function. My iterator templated as T can take either integers or float numbers, and on the following function I am trying to iterate through the container of either integers or float numbers, and store them, depending on the value type, into a new vector container.

To summarize, how do I get value type information from arbitrary iterator

```
template<typename T>
void Merge_Function(T begin, T mid, T end) {
    vector<auto> left_half (begin, mid);
    left_half.push_back(INFINITE);
    vector<auto> right_half (mid+1, end);
    right_half.push_back(INFINITE);
}
```

update:
what I am trying to do is sort of in-place merge sort.

```
vector<int> numbers = {5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 13, -6, 0, 3, 1, -2};
vector<int> L_half(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
```

This works, so I try the similar thing on the following

```
 template<typename T>
 void practice(T begin, T end) {
   auto length = end - begin;
   auto mid = length/2;
   typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type value_type;
   vector<value_type> L_half(begin, mid);
   vector<value_type> R_half(mid+1, end);
   R_half.push_back(10000);
   }
```

So in the main function
I call

```
   practice(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
```

and at first I am including the following

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <vector>
 #include <iterator>

 template<typename T>
 void practice(T begin, T end);
```

but in the line
       vector L_half(begin, mid);

I am getting the error

```
     /~~/main.cpp:105:14: No matching constructor for initialization of 'vector<int>'
```

I am using macbook air, with latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type value_type;
std::vector<value_type> left_half(begin, mid);
...
```

You can also do this in C++11:

```
typedef typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*begin)>::type value_type;
```

That will also work for lazily implemented iterator classes which don't have a `value_type` definition.

If, for some reason, you don't have an actual iterator to work with, but just the iterator type, an even more general form is this:

```
typedef typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>::type value_type;
```

Comment: No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<value_type>'  I get this... any idea?

Comment: @asd213sasdd2254121: Which typedef are you using, of the three I showed?

Comment: @asd213sasdd2254121: For the first one, did you `#include <iterator>` ?

Comment: Yeah I do. I have included that library

Comment: @asd213sasdd2254121: I'd have to see the actual code. Can you update your post with a complete example of what you are currently trying to compile?

Comment: @asd213sasdd2254121: In your practice function, `mid` is an integer.  You probably want it to be an iterator.  Try `auto mid = begin + length/2;`